# how do you get links with certain words using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, url, web, beautifulsoup, httplib2

This code is for getying links from html webpages, but I want to make it give me only the links with certain words. 
For instance, only links that have this word in there urls: `"www.mywebsite.com/word"`

My code :

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.mywebsite.com')



for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):

    if link.has_key('href'):
        print link['href']`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple string search using in. Below example print only the links which has '/website-builder' in href.

```
if '/website-builder' in link['href']:
    print link['href']
```

Full Code:

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.mywebsite.com')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_key('href'):
        if '/website-builder' in link['href']:
          print link['href']
```

Sample Output:

```
/website-builder?linkOrigin=website-builder&linkId=hd.mainnav.mywebsite
/website-builder?linkOrigin=website-builder&linkId=hd.subnav.mywebsite.mywebsite
/website-builder?linkOrigin=website-builder&linkId=hd.subnav.hosting.mywebsite
/website-builder?linkOrigin=website-builder&linkId=ct.btn.stickynavigation.easy-to-use#easy-to-use
```

Comment: can you explain what is auto? and what do you want to count in auto?

Comment: Also please accept the answer, i assume it's correct.

Comment: just set a variable count to zero before the for loop & increment it by one for every match found.

Comment: No Problem :). If want to thank you, then accept the answer :) If you don't know how to do that then here is the link explain that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: count = 0
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
     count = count + 1
print 'Count: ', count 

i make it before for loop and it doesont give me any useful sings

Comment: [count = 0
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
     count = count + 1
print 'Count: ', count ]

Comment: what is the output you got? I suggest you post a different question with code in question. this question is only for searching.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
links = [link for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')) if link.find("word") != -1]
print links
```

Of course you should replace "word" with any word you wish to filter by.